# kivy button async images

Tags: python, kivy

So my problem is that I want to have a button which uses an image from an URL. However the image doesn't show in the correct place but the button does. The image is not clickable but the button is. I want the image to be on the button and to be clickable and to send me to the following screen (ProfileScreen)

Kv file:

```
<Main_app>:
name: "Main_app"
canvas:
    Color:
        rgb: 0.216, 0.569, 0.639
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
Label:
    text: ""
    color: 0,0,0,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.251, 0.655, 0.737,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    pos_hint: {"left":1, "top":1}
    size_hint: 1, 0.0995

Label:
    text: ""
    color: 0,0,0,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.173, 0.451, 0.51,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    pos_hint: {"left":1, "top":0.9}
    size_hint: 1, 0.01

Label:
    text: ""
    color: 0,0,0,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.251, 0.655, 0.737,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    pos_hint: {"left":1, "top":0.12}
    size_hint: 1, 0.25

Label:
    text: ""
    color: 0,0,0,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.173, 0.451, 0.51,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    pos_hint: {"left":1, "top":0.13}
    size_hint: 1, 0.01

    Button:
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        size: 100,100
        pos_hint: {"x":0.90, "top":1.0}
        on_press: app.root.current = "OpeningScreen"
        AsyncImage:
            source: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/eye-24-256.png'
            keep_ratio: True
            pos_hint: {"x":0.90, "top":1.0}


<ProfileScreen>:
    name: "ProfileScreen"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.216, 0.569, 0.639
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Python file:

```
  class ProfileScreen(Screen):
        pass

    class Main_app(Screen):
        pass

    AppKv = Builder.load_file("App.kv")


    class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return AppKv

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyApp().run()
```

Here are some pictures of how it looks like.
http://prntscr.com/iihmcc

Comment: In that image what is the button?

Comment: The Image is not clickable. The gray part acts like the button but the image doesnt go in the same place as the button.

Comment: I'm a little blind, you could provide a [mcve] where I can reproduce what the image is trying to show to understand you and help you

Comment: I edited the question. I hope that helps.

Comment: Try patching the code you have placed and I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/8g1lR, you could improve your [mcve] to get your example

Comment: Maybe now? It should look like on the picture I put for an example.

Comment: `load_file()` does not return anything so `AppKv` is `None`, you can correct that error, build must return Main_app: `class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main_app()`

Comment: Its code as it can not be executed, besides the indentation of the .kv is inadequate, this is my test code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/25a1fa088044d35b58cccf7e03e17edf, obtaining the following: https://imgur.com/a/KBSAl

Comment: I get Following error with your .kv:  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/eyllanesc/main.py", line 8, in <module>
     AppKv=Builder.load_file("App.kv")
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
parse_level
     'Invalid data after declaration')
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "/home/eyllanesc/App.kv", line 2:
 ...
       1:<Main_app>:
 >>    2:name: "Main_app"
       3:canvas:
       4:    Color:

Comment: Thats interesting. It works for me and all the code is exactly the same. And also I tried your code and it still does the same thing. The button goes to the Top Left.

Comment: What version of kivy are you using? I've tried it with kivy 1.10

Comment: Never mind. I copied your code into a brand new file and it works now. But I dont know why it doesnt work in my kv file...

Comment: Your .kv does not have a correct structure

Comment: Interesting. I deleted my code and copied your code replacing my with it. And now it works perfectly. I see that my code was written with many errors unlike yours. However I wanted it to be in the Top Right corner and it has the same pos like last time.

Comment: interesting, review what are your other mistakes, bye :D

Comment: Really thankful for your help! Also I have some questions. Could we chat so I could tell you my questions?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new widget type which implements Image and ButtonBehavior. I had the same problem and found that somewhere. Here is the code I used to create that new widget. It is not for a .kv file though.

First you create a new class with extending the Image and ButtonBehavior class:

```
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def on_press(self):
        print("on_press")
```

Then you can create a new instance of the class you just created with a function like this:

```
@staticmethod
def create_image_button_widget(file_name):
    """
    Function used to create an ImageButton widget.
    :param file_name: Filename of the image to be used as source
    :return: The ImageButton object.
    """
    image_to_add = ImageButton()
    image_to_add.source = "source_of_image.jpg"
    image_to_add.name = file_name
    return image_to_add
```